# How to set dataReplicationFactor in startup progress of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does anyone know what the parameter `dataReplicationFactor` in Apache IoTDB is for? When I tried to startup IoTDB, an error reported that the `dataReplicationFactor` setting in DataNode was wrong. I don't understand what this parameter means, so anyone can explain this to me, and suggest any possible reason that this parameter may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `dataReplicationFactor` in Apache IoTDB is used to set the number of consensus copies of the DataNodes. You can check whether the version of the cluster IoTDB is consistent for each server, and whether there is data in the `data` directory before starting. The error you met may because the DataNode is not started successfully. You can try to clear the `log` files and then restart IoTDB, and you should know the specific reason by looking through the logs. Also, make sure there is no `data` directory at startup.